# Xmodmap not remapping mouse buttons

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xmodmap

My .Xmodmap file contains this line: `keycode 115 = Pointer_Button1`. I used Xev to confirm that 115 is the end key on my keyboard. When I press the end key on my keyboard, everything works as usual (after `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`). The End key still does its usual behaviour and does not press the mouse key. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: run `xkbset m` before assigning Pointer_Button1

Comment: @Andra what's xkbset, how do I install it? I get `command not found`.